# http 404 errorThe origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I am new to spring mvc and I have done have everything proper seeing a tutorial.But still I am facing Http 404 error -The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.why is that so?

I'm using IntelliJ IDE and tomcat server to run my code.
under WEB-INF/ I have all dispatcher-servlet,jsp,web.xml file.

this is the controller class. I tried both the methods(/hello and /hi) but I'm not able to get successful results.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public ModelAndView hiworld(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("hello");
        modelAndView.addObject("message","hi bro its ok");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

this the dispatcher-servlet.xml.

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>
```

this is my web.xml file
 Spring MVC Application

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In hello.jsp file, I am printing the message

```
<body>
<p>${message}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

expected result was the successful execution of jsp file.
but I'm getting HTTP 404 ERROR-The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: please help me in this

Comment: Try to annotate with @RequestMapping("/") your class. This will tell Spring that the path of this class is the root. Then, it should be accessible at "http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello".

Comment: Also, if it's a new project go with Spring Boot 2.0 rather than plain spring. You'll get rid of all xml wiring.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<context:component-scan base-package = "package_with_your_controller" />` to dispatcher-servlet.xml. This tag will be use to activate Spring MVC annotation scanning capability which allows to make use of annotations like `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` etc.